# No aparecen imágenes en LATEX

Tags: latex

El problema es el siguiente:
Si inserto las imágenes directamente:

```
\includegraphics{nombre de la imagen}
```

Sí se inserta, pero como son varias, se colocan unas encima de las otras.
Y haciéndolo de la siguiente forma:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{nombre de la imagen}
\end{figure}
```

La imagen sencillamente no aparece. Lo he hecho tanto con png como pdf.

Comment: Posiblemente la imagen sea muy grande como para caber en media página, junto con el resto del texto. El entorno `figure` trata de poner la gráfica en un "flotante" que deje sitio para más texto en la página. Si ve que no le cabe, entonces postpone la figura a otra página "solo de figuras" que pondrá al final del capítulo o del artículo. Mira a ver si no es eso lo que te está pasando. Y lo que es peor, una vez ha pospuesto una de esas figuras grandes, todas las que vayan después se posponen también para respetar el orden en que aparecen.

Comment: Ahora sí se materializa, pero al poner varias imágenes se sigue solapando

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con que se solapan. ¿Puedes poner una captura de imagen de cómo se ve la página? Y también incluye en la pregunta el código que usaste para generarla.

Comment: Buenas! El problema era que el formato de múltiples columnas y las imágenes no se llevan bien. Básicamente he quitado lo de la doble columna y ya está. Gracias!!